# "Virtual users" with Solaris 11 and ZFS share

Tags: share, solaris, nfs, smb, zfs

Is there a way to create a virtual user (e.g. a user that does not have a Solaris user) so I can set permissions on a ZFS samba share and connect to it with those credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way.

The file(s) and directories need to be stored with some way to identify who the user is who owns them, or what user(s) need permission to access them.  For a ZFS file system running on a Solaris server, that's by `uid`, either directly or indirectly, which means the user account has to exist in order to map it to anything like a SAMBA credential.

Note that the [entire Solaris VFS structure](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/vnode.h#350) relies upon each element having a `uid`:

```
typedef struct vattr {
    uint_t      va_mask;    /* bit-mask of attributes */
    vtype_t     va_type;    /* vnode type (for create) */
    mode_t      va_mode;    /* file access mode */
    uid_t       va_uid;     /* owner user id */
    gid_t       va_gid;     /* owner group id */
    dev_t       va_fsid;    /* file system id (dev for now) */
    u_longlong_t    va_nodeid;  /* node id */
    nlink_t     va_nlink;   /* number of references to file */
    u_offset_t  va_size;    /* file size in bytes */
    timestruc_t va_atime;   /* time of last access */
    timestruc_t va_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    timestruc_t va_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
    dev_t       va_rdev;    /* device the file represents */
    uint_t      va_blksize; /* fundamental block size */
    u_longlong_t    va_nblocks; /* # of blocks allocated */
    uint_t      va_seq;     /* sequence number */
} vattr_t;
```

And using ACLs won't remove that need for a `uid`, as ZFS ACLs in the end come down to the numeric ID of the entity.  See the source code at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/fs/zfs/sys/zfs_acl.h#48